# How to add the camera loaded by fbxloader to scene in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using fbxloader of three.js to add model to my scene, and i've seen that the lastest version of fbxloader.js (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js) can read the **camera** data of .fbx file.

**But how to add this camera to my scene?**

Here is my current code which can only get the original model.

```
            var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'url', function( object ) {
                scene.add( object );                    
            }, onProgress, onError );
```

Comment: you dont need to add the camera to the scene.

Comment: @gaitat I do, but I want the loader to get camera's attributes from fbx file.

Comment: looking at the source you posted the loader creates the required three.js camera.

Comment: @gaitat  yes it did create a camera. But it seems that that camera wasn't added to the scene automatically, any code I should add to my html page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'url', function( object ) {

    object.traverse( function( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Camera ) {

            scene.add( child );

        }

    } );

    scene.add( object );

}, onProgress, onError );
```

but you should now that the camera is already included in the scene.